# iTunes Connect - Get active user installs by app version

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I understand that download figures can be retrieved from `iTunes Connect` in daily, weekly monthly or yearly basis.
If I have three app versions, say `1.0`, `1.1` and `1.2`. Can I get the number of users currently using different versions respectively?

Say,

```
version 1.0: 100
version 1.1: 200
version 1.2: 800
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately, `iTunes Connect` does not provide this information. Right now, you can only filter by territory, platform, App Store category, content type and transaction type. There is no way of getting the information how many users are using a particular version of the app since `iTunes Connect` is not a tracking tool.

[image]

If you want to collect more information about your app, how, when, where and by what kind of audience your app is used you should integrate one of the Analytics `SDK`.

Examples:
[Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/),
[Flurry Analytics](http://www.flurry.com/flurry-analytics.html),
[Mixpanel](https://mixpanel.com/), and many [more](http://www.apptamin.com/blog/app-analytics-tools/).

Comment: New version of the App Analytics has been released. Is it possible to do it now? This can be done in Google Play Dashboard. Any idea if this can be done in the new iTunes Analytics Dashboard?

Comment: Answer by @koiyu is the right answer now. This answer is outdated.

Answer (score 22):

The new version of iTunes Connect includes [**App Analytics**](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-analytics/) section, which can—among other tricks—show you how many **active devices*** you've had within a time range. It's also possible to get statistics on how many **sessions*** (= app active for at least 2 seconds) you've had within a time range. Both parameters are groupable by app version.

App Analytics has its own section on iTunes Connect, next to Sales and Trends.

What App Analytics doesn't show is how many installations are idly sitting in user's springboard, like Play Dashboard does.

*) User must had opted-in to share data with developers. This is usually done on device activation, after major upgrades and at any time via settings.

Answer (score 6):

To get statistics about the installation of your app versions by following the steps:

1. Open [appstoreconnect panel](http://appstoreconnect.apple.com)
2. Select **App Analytics**
   [image]
3. Select your app
   [image]
4. Select **Metrics** and under **Usage** select **Installations**

[image]
5. From the filter select **App Version**

[image]
6. Enjoy statistics

[image]

Comment: view by app version is disabled at my end why so?

Answer (score 5):

Goto Appstore Connect --> App Analytics --> Installations (Under Usage) --> View BY (Apply Filter [App version : X.Y])

The result can differ on App user preferences